# No _id field when adding object to array in collection

Tags: reactjs, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection in Mongodb I'm accessing in my app and connecting through ReactJS and mongoose.  On this collection I have a property that is set to an Array type.  When I add to that Array, it does so successfully, however I DO NOT see an _id field that should be automatically be created.  Why would this be happening?  Thanks.

Comment: The `_id` property should be automatically added by mongoose to all sub documents unless you specify the `_id: false` option. Can you post your schema? If your array is an array of strings, numbers etc then they won't have an `_id` but all sub documents will. See [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id fields are only added to top-level-documents, not to sub-documents in arrays. If you want to have ids on the sub-documents, you need to add them to your schema manually when saving.